# How to differentiate localStorage from storing each file on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I've made a simple jQuery script which stores values `"voted1"`, `"voted2"`, `"voted3"` in `localStorage`. The problem is that on click it stores all values at the same time, and I need it per click as it should be later called (e.g. if `"value3"` exists begin jQuery logic...)

I can't figure this out, after weeks of testing..

HTML:

```
[gallery link="none" size="medium" ids="102,13,27,25,23,15" orderby="rand"]
<div class="exists" style="display: none;">Thank you for voting!</div>
```

CSS:

```
.gallery-item a {
    background-color: black;
    border: 1px solid orange;
        border-radius: 6px;
        color: orange;
        display: inline-table;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 32%;
}
.exists {
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 18px;
    box-shadow: 1px 3px 20px -3px grey inset;
    display: block;
    height: 32%;
    left: 24%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-left: 12%;
    padding-top: 6%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 23%;
    width: 36%;
    z-index: 999999;
    color: olivedrab;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: context-menu;
}
.voted {
    background-color: green !important;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var voteLink = $('.gallery-item a');
    var votedYes = $('.exists');
        voteLink.one('click', function() {
           // localStorage.setItem('voted1', 'yes1');
            $(this).text('Thank you!');
            $(this).addClass('voted');
            })
        voteLink.one('click', function() {
           // localStorage.setItem('voted2', 'yes2');
            $(this).text('Thank you!');
            $(this).addClass('voted');
            })
        voteLink.one('click', function() {
            localStorage.setItem('voted3', 'yes3');
            $(this).text('Thank you!');
            $(this).addClass('voted');
            if($('.voted').length === 3){
            voteLink.fadeOut('slow');
            $('.exists').fadeIn(1800);
            }
        if (localStorage.getItem("voted3")) {
        voteLink.remove();
        votedYes.fadeIn(1800);
        }
        });
```

As I said, on first click it places all values in localStorage and I need this separated.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Is requirement to store each vote separately at different `localStorage` property, or overwrite each vote in single `localStorage` property ?

Comment: Each vote should be stored separately depending on click, no overwriting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var voteLink = $(".gallery-item a");
    var votedYes = $(".exists");
    if (localStorage.getItem("count") === null) {
      localStorage.setItem("count", 1)
    }
    if (!(localStorage.getItem("voted3") === "yes3")) {
      var i = Number(localStorage.getItem("count")),
        fn = function(e) {
          if (i < 3) {
            localStorage.setItem("voted" + i, "yes" + i);
            $(this).text("Thank you! for vote " + i)
              .addClass("voted" + i);
            localStorage.setItem("count", 1 + i);
            i = Number(localStorage.getItem("count"));
          } else {
            localStorage.setItem("voted" + i, "yes" + i);
            $(this).text("Thank you! for vote " + i)
              .addClass("voted" + i)
              .fadeOut("slow");
            if (localStorage.getItem("voted3") === "yes3") {
              voteLink.remove();
              votedYes.fadeIn(1800);
            }
          }
        };
      voteLink.on("click", fn);
    } else {
      // if `localStorage` has property `"voted3"` and value equals `"yes3"`, 
      // do stuff
    }
  })
```

Comment: Wow.. just wow. You are amazing. You did it! What would be nice to have if when user votes and reloads the page, the voted element remains with the class .voted. If there is anything I can do to return this favor, please let me know. Is there anywhere I can leave a review of you? For more than 4 hours you've been dealing with this... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

*Caveat*: This answer may be completely off, since your question comes without all the details of your use case. However ...

The following code assumes that ...

- up to 3 votes shall be recorded in localStorage
- in order to cast the vote `n+1`, vote `n` must have been recorded before.

Either register the handlers contingent on the content in localStorage:

```
if (
      localStorage.getItem("voted1")
   && !localStorage.getItem("voted2")
) {
     voteLink.one('click', function() {
         localStorage.setItem('voted2', 'yes2');
         //...
     });
}
```

... or test the localStorage contents inside your event handler:

```
fn_vote2 = function() {
    if (
          localStorage.getItem("voted1")
       && !localStorage.getItem("voted2")
    ) {
        localStorage.setItem('voted2', 'yes2');
        //...
        voteLink.off('click', fn_vote2);
    }
};
voteLink.on('click', fn_vote2);
```

The generalization for `vote1`, `vote3` should come easy. Note that the latter solution implies that you register the handler not just for a single event. Instead you deregister it upon success.

The advantage of the method is the option for cascaded voting without reloading the page.

Btw, since localStorage persists over sessions, it is advisable not to use generic keys like `vote<n>`.